# Filter plain org file by property (file not in agenda)

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have an org file with this structure:

```
* Books


** READING Some book title :@nonfiction:@psychology:
:PROPERTIES:
:AUTHOR: Cialdin 
:PURCHASE_DATE: 25/02/2020
:END:
```

How would I filter by `author=cildin`? Basically something like `org-match-sparse-tree` but for property key value pairs?

Comment: Does `M-x org-sparse-tree` not what you want? First you are asked how you want to filter and one of the options is `[p]roperty`. If you type `p` you can give `AUTHOR` as property name and `Cialdin` as value. Tab-completion works for that input.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, it does, thanks. Didn't know that command. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-sparse-tree` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

First you are asked how you want to filter and one of the options is `[p]roperty`.
If you type <kbd>p</kbd> you can give `AUTHOR` as property name and `Cialdin` as value.

Tab-completion works for that input.